# who has the competence to define a term in music (if it has not been known or used before)

Tags: discussion

Zlet's say "paraphrasing" in music as an analogy of paraphrasing in psychology and psychiatry?
or in other words: how much reputation will  I need to determine or define a term?  will 40k fit for it? how many doctor titles do I need? how many books must  I have written?

The term **paraphrase** seems quite clearly defined. 
Right coming from searching another term for the fill-ins, echo-ing, answering in the dialog of 2 instruments, singer and piano or guitar, I proposed the term "paraphrasing". Now I've found paraphrasing used in of other answers and comments. I don't think that there is evidence of it. If yes, thank you for answering.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6zWjUhfj-M

Comment: I think anyone can, but until it's recognized globally/internationally, then I don't see the point in pushing the idea on this site...

Answer (score 1):

This is not anything to do with Music.SE, or in fact any Stack Exchange site. Meta sites here are for questions about how Stack Exchange works.